# Undefined object in Stickit/Backbone model after selecting result from Select2 Ajax

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, jquery-select2, backbone-stickit

Here is the jsfiddle , I have used almost the same fiddle [My Fiddle with Ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/atummala/40rwfybf/) and here is Matt's [Stickit MultiSelect Select2 with an array](http://jsfiddle.net/px6UP/51/)
but added an ajax attribute to the select config.

Clicking on the Result, the model sets an undefined attribute to the model
`console.log(this.model.attributes)` result friends:[1,2,undefined].

The change event just calls the getVal function , which returns an undefined value 
here 
`getVal: function($el) {
      var selected = $el.find('option:selected');

```
  if ($el.prop('multiple')) {
    return _.map(selected, function(el) {
      **return Backbone.$(el).data('stickit-bind-val');**
    });
  } else {
    return selected.data('stickit-bind-val');
  }
}`
```

I think unlike the update function which adds select options, clicking the result is not adding the option or calling the addSelectOptions function.

But when using the `getVal:function($el,event,options){return $el.val(val);}` returns just the values [1,2,4].But if I have a nested collection it just returns the values not the whole object.

NEED THE WHOLE OBJECT RETURNED FROM THE AJAX CALL AND SET IT TO THE MODEL ATTRIBUTE ON SELECTION.